# Correct way to reconnect to database after disconnect using Qt and QSqlDatabase

Tags: qt, reconnect, qsqldatabase, disconnection

What is the correct way to reconnect to database using Qt4 upon disconnect?

I'm using Sql Server 2012 over ODBC. If I detect disconnection using SELECT 1 query, and then do

```
db.close();
db.open()
```

I receive exceptions on other opened SqlQueries (in driver) which are trying to use next() method.

If I do nothing with database, only trying to execute new queries using the same database - any exec() returns false with warning "Connection error".

Comment: The problem was solved only by rewriting Qt Db driver, as far as I remember